# Adding UL to jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It seems like whenever I try to add a UL inside of the containers when using jQuery UI - Tabs, it breaks the javascript. Is there a way I can use a UL inside of these containers that I am missing?

Thanks

```
<div id="tabs">
        <div id="fragment-1">
            <h4>Pre-Press Requirements</h4>
            <span class="peesinal">&#149; SAMPLE of final artwork with noted sizes.</span><br /><br />
            <span class="peesinal">&#149; NATIVE FILES & High Resolution PDF preferred. Files must be created or saved to the listed accepted file formats.</span><br /><br />
            <span class="peesinal">&#149; FONTS used in files need to be supplied in a separate folder marked "fonts". Please ensure all families (screen & printer) fonts are supplied for the job.</span><br /><br />
            <span class="peesinal">&#149; IMAGES must be saved as CMYK and no less than 300dpi. NO RGB FILES! We  
                prefer images to be TIF or EPS formats. If you are submitting artwork for spot
                color printing vector artwork is preferred. Your images should be supplied in
                a separate folder marked "links". This will ensure proper reproduction of  
                your artwork.</span><br /><br />

                <span class="peesinal">&#149; COLORS need to be clearly specified. Pantone (PMS) colors preferred. Please
                specify if job is to be printed CMYK, spot color, etc.</span><br /><br />

                <span class="peesinal">&#149; BLEEDS should be no less than .25"</span><br /><br />

                <span class="peesinal">&#149; PDF's should be High Resolution. Please include any spot colors or CMYK format for full color printing. NO RGB FILES! All bleeds should be included with trim marks. All fonts must be embedded or outlined. No "layered" PDF files.</span>
                <a id="fileFormatsBlock" href="#fileFormats">
                    <div id="monitor"></div>
                    <span class="filelink">Acceptable File Formats</span>
                </a>
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2">

            <div id="caption" class="ui-corner-all"><p>Our presses are all capable of sizes up to 11" x  17" using spot color or full color.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-3">
            <p>USA Quickprint has complete in house bindery to finish each job to meet your needs.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment-4">
            <p>We provide high speed digital black and white with in line punching, folding, and stapling. Or you can choose to upgrade to high speed digital full color with sizes up to 12" x 18".</p>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li class="prepressTab ui-corner-all"><a href="#fragment-1"></a></li>
            <li class="pressroomTab ui-corner-all"><a href="#fragment-2"></a></li>
            <li class="binderyTab ui-corner-all"><a href="#fragment-3"></a></li>
            <li class="copyTab ui-corner-all"><a href="#fragment-4"></a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the actual tab declarations inside your `#tabs` div, like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1">Tab 1 Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2">Tab 2 Title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3">Tab 3 Title</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[You can see a demo with this fix here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkS3g/), the only other change was to close the `#tabs` div, probably just a closing `</div>` tag not pasted with your question.

Comment: @Nick - Doesn't that just burn you up?

Comment: @patrick - What's that? The answer below being updated to follow this one several times inside the 5 minute timer...or something else? :)

Comment: @Nick - Precisely. Although, I see you're holding strong with the 6 downers. You're a nice guy. :o)

Comment: nick,

sorry, i didn't paste all of the code - i do have the declarations and am still having trouble. i've updated the code above

Comment: @Dave - You shouldn't downvote when you change the question *then* an answer isn't correct...

Comment: haha, sorry dude, i didn't mean to down, just remove it marked as answer. i appreciate your response, really!

Comment: @Dave - Your markup works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/xkS3g/1/ Something else going on in your full page?

Comment: crap.... that is the updated code i wrote in the last hour or so that doesnt actually have an li, but a bunch of separate spans... if you replace the spans with a ul, you should see what i mean..

Comment: @Dave - Take a look at the [tabs on the bottom demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#bottom), if that's what you're after, adjust your code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xkS3g/3/

Comment: it's not, im just trying to put an unordered list inside of the content divs and it is throwing the design all off, like tabs isnt being applied properly. tabs at the top are just fine.

Comment: @Dave - In that case, just put the `<ul>` first (not after everything) under the `<div id="tabs">`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xkS3g/4/

Answer (score 0):

There is no closing `</div>` for your opening #tabs div.
Furthermore there are no tab links declared.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Tab Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, recently.

After I figured out that moving the UL for the panel navigation above the panels fixed my issue, I used CSS to re-position my navigation.

```
<!--Begin jquery ui tabs-->
    <section class="feature">
        <div class="nav-panel">
            <ul class="ui-tabs-nav container">                  
                <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-panel-1"><a href="#panel-1">Dean's Message</a></li>
                <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-panel-2"><a href="#panel-2">M.D. Program</a></li>
                <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-panel-3"><a href="#panel-3">Joint M.D. Programs</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </div><!--end panel nav-->

        <div class="rotator">
            <div class="panel ui-tabs-panel" id="panel-1">
                <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="555" height="327" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Mp1uDB4Z3dI?rel=0&#38;autohide=1"></iframe>
                <h2><a href="/deans">Words of Welcome from the Dean</a></h2>
                    <p>A message from Dean Jones</p>
            </div><!--end panel 1-->

            <div class="panel ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" id="panel-2">
                <img src="/images/sized/images/content/adm-feature2-555x327-555x327.jpg" alt="Student practicing on a dummy" />
                <h2><a href="/programs/md-program">Excellence in Medical Education</a></h2>
                    <p>M.D. Program at the Miller School of Medicine</p>
            </div><!--end panel 2-->

            <div class="panel ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" id="panel-3">
                <img src="/images/sized/images/content/UceRf-XL--555x327.jpg" alt="Miller School of Medicine Students" />
                <h2><a href="/programs/md-program">Joint M.D. Programs</a></h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>M.D./Ph.D.</li>
                        <li>M.D./M.B.A.</li>
                        <li>M.D./J.D.</li>
                    </ul>
            </div><!--end panel 3-->

        </div><!--end rotator-->
    </section><!--end feature section-->
```

CSS:

```
section.feature {
height: 350px;
position: relative;
}

section.feature div.nav-panel {
bottom: 0;
height: 24px;
position: absolute;
}
```